# Check if a MySQL statement is reading or writing

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I'm currently working on a PHP extension where I'll be giving users the authority to write an SQL (in a `textarea`), and I'll be executing it.

But for obvious security issues, I'd like to "validate" the SQL before actually executing it. One thing I know for sure is that the SQL my users are supposed to write is only to read/fetch data. So what I want to do is check if the SQL is reading (SELECT, SHOW) or writing (UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, CREATE, INSERT, etc.), without actually executing it (for obvious reasons).

So is there any way of acheiving this in PHP/MySQL?

**NOTE** I can't restrict the MySQL user's access, since the same user is being used in other extensions, and needs write access. I can't create a new user just for this either.

Comment: But if the statement starts with SELECT it is a reading query. Why not simply use regexp or even strpos?

Comment: What if the statement is "SELECT * FROM my_table;DROP TABLE my_table;"?

Comment: It's two queries. explode them on ';' or use regexp to explode the user's query

Comment: That was just an example. To find out all possible SQL injection types, I'd have to do a course on ethical hacking or hire a professional hacker maybe. lol

Answer (score 1):

Wow. this sounds like a minefield!! Rather you than me buddy! 
My thoughts:

- you could obviously dissect the SQL submitted to look for (and remove) unwanted commands (`UPDATE`, `INSERT` etc...), fields, table name and that there is just **one** statement (no dodgy secondary commands running after or before the main select)
- The SQL (if it's a `SELECT`) should follow a pattern to an extent so you can make sure it *is* a SELECT statement
- You could limit the scope of the SELECT statement that can be run i.e. no joins
- make sure only A-Za-z0-9 chars are submitted

In addition, to test syntax validity of it without running potentially dangerous SQL on your DB you could perhaps wrap the execution in a transaction and always rollback...so maybe:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM The_Table WHERE field1 = 'test';

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

...just my initial thoughts! hope they help.

UPDATE:

You could use an SQL Parser as you suggested below. This kind of thing could break down the intent of the SQL submitted allowing you to make sure all is OK (or as OK as you can verify!) 
https://github.com/greenlion/PHP-SQL-Parser

Personally I would throw the parser plus some/all of the logic above at this. There is a lot of scope for PAIN! :O

Comment: This is sort of along the lines of my initial thought as well. I was wondering whether there are some libraries already developed which parses the SQL to check this maybe? Because it'll be very difficult to consider all possible SQL injections a hacker might try

Comment: Additionally, I was wondering, how does MySQL manage the user level operation restrictions? Maybe I could do the same?

Comment: I've added a possible parser but there are loads out there im sure. Re: user scope - i can imagine writing your own routine to limit this will kind of go hand in hand with this process anyway. If you could create a new read-only user for this method it would _really_ help your cause.

Comment: Creating the read-only user is my last resort anyway. Just wondering if there's an alternative to that

Answer (score 0):

```
 if( !is_null( $query ) && !is_null( $serial ) )
    $query = "/* ".basename($serial[0]).":".$serial[1]." */ ".$query;

// Determine if the query is a read or write operation
$query_type = strtoupper(substr(trim($query), 0, 6));
$read_operations = ['SELECT', 'SHOW', 'DESCRIBE', 'EXPLAIN'];
$is_read_operation = in_array($query_type, $read_operations);

// Set the database to use based on the query type
if ($is_read_operation) {
    $database = 'read_db'; // set the name of your read database here
} else {
    $database = 'write_db'; // set the name of your write database here
}
```

Something like this can be used to determine which db connection to use based on the query string